# MongoDB update по аналогии SQL UPDATE from join values

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb, mongodb-query

Добрый день подскажите есть ли в mongodb возможность сделать за 1 запрос update by list key value как в sql UPDATE from join values?

Answer (score 0):

Да, обратите на документацию по монго.

В любом случае `update` изменяет только одну таблицу в одно и тоже время как и SQL DB. Если вы хотите update by list key то смотрите

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#examples

Параметер   Тип         Описание

`query`     `document`  Критерии выбора для `update` идентичны что и в методе `find ()`.

Comment: Посмотрел , так и не нашел то что нужно, увидел только bulk insert .